# Error while recording UI script in Neoload

Tags: performance, testing, scripting, redirect, neoload

I'm facing an error in Neoload while recording a UI script. The redirection is not happening, I'm getting the code 200 for the status of the page instead of 301. Please help me out.

Comment: You have to be more precise : 
- Did you corelates all parameters ?
- the http 200 code is a real http 200 or is there an error on the page ? 
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the dynamic value inside the recorded response. You can do that by using the variable extractor and then filtering out to the response body.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).